# Continue button is not working on Magento checkout after selecting Payment Method

Tags: checkout

Continue button is not working on Magento checkout after selecting Payment Method.

**Error in console**

> TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
>
> card_number = document.querySelector('#ccsave_cc_number').value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you killed the input field with the id `ccsave_cc_number` in your theme.

Beside this, be warned, you are only allowed to use CC_SAVE, if you are PCI-DSS complaint.

Comment: thankyou so much for the reply, can you please explain a bit more about what should i do.

Comment: Make sure your theme contains an input field with the id.

Comment: If you need more help, please ask concrete questions.

Comment: i added this id "ccsave_cc_number" to th button, now its showing error to next line :

exp_month = document.querySelector('#ccsave_expiration').value

Comment: get the default template and make sure all the input fields are available - or just disable ccsave as payment method.

Comment: thankyou so much  :)